# Checking if Active Directory username exists using following conditions

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, active-directory-group

```
$lastname = "xyz"
$firstname = "abc"

$username = $lastname_$firstname -or $firstname.$lastname #error
```

In this line how to check these conditions?

```
$aduser = get-aduser -f samaccountname -eq $username
if($true){
    write-host "username exist"
}
else{
     write-host "user doesn't exist"
}
```

Comment: Is the users SamAccountName **really** like `Sanket_Khed` or `Sanket.Khed`? Probably not, so why not test for `get-aduser -filter 'Name -eq $username'` (given that $username could be `"$firstname $lastname"` or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to check if a username exists or not, then you would test whether `$aduser` is not `$null`.

You also need to specify `sAMAccountName -eq` for each condition that might be met. And you also need quotes around the filter.

```
$lastname = "xyz"
$firstname = "abc"

$aduser = Get-ADUser -f "sAMAccountName -eq '$($lastname)_$firstname' -or sAMAccountName -eq '$firstname.$lastname'"
if ($aduser -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "username exist"
} else {
    Write-Host "user doesn't exist"
}
```

Comment: After this i want to check if user already exist i want to create username adding 1 in front if 1 also exist then 2 until the username is unique. eg. sanket.khed exist then sanket.khed1

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
     get-aduser -f samaccountname -eq $username
     Write-Output "Username $username exists"
}
catch
{
     Write-Output "Username $username does not exist"
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: `Get-ADUser` does not throw an exception when the account is not found.

Comment: Cheers @Gabriel Luci I'll revise

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this at the moment, but if all you have is a first name and a last name, you can do something like this:

```
$aduser = Get-ADUser -filter "(GivenName -eq $firstname) -and (Surname -eq $lastname)"
if ($aduser) {
    Write-Host "user exists"
} else {
    Write-Host "user doesn't exist"
}
```

Or combine the `$firstname` and `$lastname` to become the user's full name and try this:

```
$username = "$firstname $lastname"
$aduser = Get-ADUser -filter "Name -eq $username"
if ($aduser) {
    Write-Host "user exists"
} else {
    Write-Host "user doesn't exist"
}
```

Comment: No man i want to check the condition like user will only give input as firstname and lastname. And i wanted to create username using $lastname_$firstname and $firstname.$lastname and check this username already exist in AD or not?